# Fractional, non-integral combinatoric compositions

Tags: co.combinatorics

We all know a lot about integer combinatoric compositions. Has any work been done on fractional, non-integral combinatorial compositions?

An integer has a finite set of compositions or partitions.  If we were to consider fractions and non-integers the number of combinatorial  compositions would be infinite. Has any work been done in this area?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Beyond saying that an integer can be written in infinitely many ways as a sum of fractions, ramachandran, what do you expect can be said?

Comment: As far as partitions are concerned: Amritanshu Prasad has a continuous (so called timed) version of the RSK correspondence which involves Young shapes (i.e. partitions) which have finitely many rows, each with a positive real number length. Here's an arXiv link --- arxiv.org/pdf/1806.04393.pdf